# Problems following guide for basic MVC creation in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I'm following [this guide](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) and it seems to differ from what I see on my computer.

In the image where I'm supposed to pick the type, I select MVC but on my machine, I see addition options (about Azure, besides the authentication). I leave it be as it is. After that, I get the image below and it's not mentioned by the guide at all.

[image]

I'm signed in and I'm picking a name for the web site. However, the part that I'm unsure of is the database server option. I can only pick *No database* or *New server* but I want to use the one that I already have, one that's got a database that I'm using in another project (non-MVC).

How should I handle this discrepancy? Am I using a substandard guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this option is visible for you because you have a superior Visual Studio Update, but, simply, you can uncheck this a go ahead, this check in mean to create a web site or virtual machine to publish your site in Microsoft Azure, but is only an option (you need an Azure subscription), if your check this option and select for example the individual user accounts for security, you need a database, and Azure mean that you have an Azure Sql Database (this is not the only option that you can use).

If you want to follow the guide, simply, uncheck the option **Host in the cloud** and go ahead an learn MVC!

Comment: All right, then. Now, the whole point is to host it in Azure so I guess I'll just go ahead with the guide **except** that small change.